# Trouble installing mailgun API using cocoapods (iOS, Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, mailgun

I have install cocoapods using

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I now want to implement the Mailgun API (https://github.com/rackerlabs/objc-mailgun) into my application and I am having trouble.

The tutorial says paste the following code to install the library:

```
pod 'mailgun', '~> 1.0.3'
```

However I do not understand how I can do this. Because if I try it give me:

```
-bash: pod: command not found
```

And I want to paste the Mailgun libraries into "Supporting Files" in my project. I do not understand if I have to navigate to my project and install it there?

Can somebody with experience using Mailgun in Objective-C please assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file named 'Podfile' in the directory of your project. Add the line

```
pod 'mailgun', '~> 1.0.3'
```

in the file. Save and close the file.

Open the Terminal (Applications > Utilities > Terminal). In the Terminal navigate to your project:

```
cd thePath/to/your/project/directory
```

and type in

```
pod install
```

Comment: What should the file be?

Comment: I don't understand. The file is named 'Podfile' and has the content `pod 'mailgun', '~> 1.0.3'`.